# Wix Major upgrade: Skipping RemoveExistingProducts action: current configuration is maintenance mode or an uninstal

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.7

I am trying to perform a major upgrade with Wix 3.8 which is just not happening, the error I get is as below:

```
MSI (s) (B8:38) [12:42:55:680]: Doing action: RemoveExistingProducts
MSI (s) (B8:38) [12:42:55:680]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action ended 12:42:55: InstallInitialize. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (B8:38) [12:42:55:680]: Skipping RemoveExistingProducts action: current configuration is maintenance mode or an uninstall
```

I have taken care of the five cardinal rules for major upgrade in Wix:

1. ProductCode is set to "*"
2. PackageCode is set to "*"
3. UpgradeCode has not changed in the major upgrade
4. Version if greater than 1.0.0 and is incremented in the third place
5. The package is perMachine and this has not been changed for the major upgrade.

An excerpt of my wxs is given below:

```
<Upgrade Id="GUID1">
  <UpgradeVersion Minimum="4.0.0" IncludeMinimum="yes" OnlyDetect="yes" Property="NEWERVERSION"/>
  <UpgradeVersion Minimum="2.0.0"
                  IncludeMinimum="no"
                  Maximum="4.0.0"
                  IncludeMaximum="no"
                  OnlyDetect="no"
                  Property="OLDERVERSIONFORUPGRADE" />
</Upgrade>

<InstallExecuteSequence>

  <!-- Uninstall previous version before installing this one. -->
  <RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallInitialize"/>

  <Custom Action ... />
  ....
<InstallExecuteSequence/>
```

Is there something else I am missing? Any clues will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, hope it helps someone:

The NSIS script which was generating the EXE was using the flags - `REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=vdmus`, which prevents a major upgrade. Removing this cleared the path for the major upgrade!

Comment: Where or how do I change it so that I can change those flags?

Comment: I was using a commandline like this for the major upgarde: `msiexec.exe /i Setup.msi  /passive /promptrestart REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=vdmus` So all I had to do was to remove those two flags.